# Rmcorr returns a p value >1

Tags: correlation

I'm using the rmcorr package to run repeated measures on two variables with 7 time blocks per subject, with 33 subjects.

Sometimes it returns with a p value greater than 1, for example:

Repeated measures correlation

r
0.3706124

degrees of freedom
185

p-value
1.777658e-07

95% confidence interval
0.2391295 0.4887487

Any ideas on why this happens? I've searched far and wide and haven't found any information on this, but the p value is a probability statistic so theoretically it shouldn't be greater than 1?

Thanks in advance,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

For your p-value, the notation means 1.78 x 10^-7, or 0.000000178